# how to vectorize this in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, vectorization

Let's day A is a M x J matrix and B is a N x J matrix.

I would like to generate a M x N matrix S where:

```
S_ij = w^t[A_i;B_j;A_i o B_j)
```

Basically each element of the result matrix S is some vector w (a row of a matrix W) dot product with: col A_j concat with col B_j and concat with the element-wise product of each A_i and B_j for all i and j.

Ideally i would like to vectorize the operation and only use matrix form S, A and B instead of slicing and doing for loops. However I am new to tensorflow and can't seem to figure out how to do the code in matrix form as A_i o B_j seems to result in a 2d matrix and it needs to be concat with vector A_i and B_j.

Thanks

Comment: What is the shape of `W`? How is `w` related to the indices `i` and `j`?

Comment: Maybe you can give an example, or give a pseudo-code, which will be better to understand your question.